# Cannot access data from hbase with amazon ec2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, tomcat7, hbase

I have a single node hadoop machine in which hbase is running in the amazon ec2 instance.
Due to some reason the server got restarted. So i need to start hadoop and hbase again. Then its working fine, but the old data in the hbase cannot be accessed through the web-servies.

While i use the shell command its working fine, i am getting the data.

So i created the scenario on my local server machine, but its working fine.

The version details are as follows.
hadoop-0.20.2
hbase-0.90.5
apache-tomcat-7.0.30
in Amazon ec2 medium instance

And I use restful web-services with Orm-hbase to access data.

Comment: check your Elastic IP once. is it still attached?

Comment: yes i double checked, its k ok